# Constrain a generic type to be a literal type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

My question is two-fold:

1. I would like to know if there is a way in TypeScript to constrain a generic to be a literal type of some kind. What I mean by this is something like `function foo<T is a string literal>(...)`. The closest I have come to this behaviour is `function foo<T extends string>`, but this allows unions of string literals and the type "string" itself as values for T.
2. If this is not possible in TypeScript 2.1, would it make sense from a design perspective to implement such a feature?

My use-case is to define a curried function `prop` like this:

```
function prop<K extends string, U>(name: K): <T extends { [P in K]: U  }>(obj: T) => T[K] {
    return (obj) => obj[name];
}

prop<'name', number>("name")({
    name: 3
})
```

This example works as expected if `K` is a string literal, but the typechecking of the function kind of breaks down `K` is `string`.

I know it's a bit contrived; please not my goal is not to solve a practical problem (although it would) but more to experiment with TypeScript's type system.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the goal to make a function that can retrieve arbitrary properties from an object in a type safe way?

Comment: I actually do have a practical problem I would like to solve with this and it may actually be possible with Typescript 4 in 2022: associate a string literal with a type, like in `class KeyedType<k is literal, T>` such that I can use `keyed: KeyedType<'x', SomeX>`  in, say, `get<K, X>(key: KeyedType<K, X>): X` and can be sure that the `keyed` will result in an `X`.

Comment: @Aegis, meanwhile we have this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185333/2954288, you could flag your question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're putting the cart before the horse in terms of your generic constraints: there is no sense in trying to constrain the allowed keys before you know the object.

Here's an example that does what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
function propGetter<O>(o: O): <K extends keyof O>(key: K) => O[K] {
    return k => o[k];
}

let prop = propGetter({
    id: 10,
    firstName: "Dununuh Hunudunuh"
});

let id = prop("id");               // number
let firstName = prop("firstName"); // string
let foo = prop("foo");             // Type error
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However that's the "easy way out". I was specifically trying to do the opposite: constrain the object based on the property name. The use-case I was thinking of would be with functional lenses.