# Typescript: Enforce a type to be "string literal" and not <string>

Tags: string, typescript, literals, branding

## Problem

Is there a way in Typescript to define a type that is only a [**string literal**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), excluding `string` itself?

Note that I am not talking about a certain list of string literal; for which, a simple union of `"Value1" | "Value2"`, or an `enum` type would work.  I am talking about **any string literal, but not `string` itself.**

#### Example Code

```
type OnlyStringLiterals = ...; // <--- what should we put here?

const v1: OnlyStringLiterals = "hi"; // should work
const v2: OnlyStringLiterals = "bye"; // should work
// and so should be for any single string value assigned

// But:
const v3: OnlyStringLiterals = ("red" as string); // should NOT work -- it's string
```

## Use Case

I am doing [Branding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148229/typescript-how-to-expect-exact-class-instance-as-function-parameter) on the types in my code, and I am passing a brand name, as a template, to my parent class.  See the code below:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<
    BRAND_T extends string,
    VALUE_T = string
> {
    constructor(private readonly _value: VALUE_T) { }

    getValue(): VALUE_T { return this._value; }

    private _Brand?: BRAND_T; // required to error on the last line, as intended!
}

class FirstName extends MyAbstractClass<"FirstName"> {
}

class AdminRole extends MyAbstractClass<"AdminRole"> {
}

class SubClassWithMissedName extends MyAbstractClass<string> {
   // I want this to error! ........................ ^^^^^^
}

function printName(name: FirstName) {
    console.log(name.getValue()); 
}

const userFirstName = new FirstName("Alex");
const userRole = new AdminRole("Moderator");

printName(userRole); // Already errors, as expected
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgTwILmjggGFV0AeAIQCVcA5AEQH0AVBAUwA8J2A7AEwyQoAS14BzADQIAargAyAVQCirBAF4EwseIB8CAN4AoBKaQB7XsICu8c1AAUAB1EA3YDwRR2wfpeTYCEzuyNbsAFyyCiqsAJSGCAC+RiZm4uwQMsCh7A6xkXJKqmwGXhnWULwIEAAWImAAdMHZYQDcSSlmCC4i7p5MlDACAPyRNPTMLK1GyUYoaBgAYiJQkHTAALbsHNx8glh4BDDwpAvkAETLqxDrW+f6xrPz6Ai4-Bti1ObI21w8AhgcPhhERThRzm8Prwvj97oYZilnhhqMABOYNgBlaA6Hb-fZAo6gshgcjaCQPBAAekpCHIAFo6QgAO6oxC1erVcwcKBQewAQgRRgAZtZePARJZuqJeDdNrleHLIlc1nL4sYurBLGBvuwGshzOIHAqtg10pkWrlYrF2oLNVZENYwOwoMrZVsNAheOwmQhXbdchCfpxzta5lqHU6oDDtpovT7IZ8dQ5zphzPxnR57CHpkYejL-Q5Hc7o9aqTTcMhvL5As7eatpGgdk52PB2PwjEA)

I want to make sure every subclass is passing exactly a **string literal**, and not just `string` to the parent class.

Comment: Your use case does not really explain why you need it. As long as the value is the same - why do you care how it was produced?

Comment: @zerkms, I had simplified the use case.  Just updated the use case to reflect something closer to my real-world problem.  I am concerned about someone missing to pass it.

I know one can still claim removing the default type of the second generic type (VALUE_T = string) can enforce two types to be passed; and I can counter-argue that well, since in 95% of the cases the value is string, I rather have a default type for it. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found an answer that works for my use case, but is not the most reusable one.  Just sharing it anyway.

#### Thought Process

I believe it's not possible to have one solid type to represent what I wanted, because I cannot even think what will show up in VS Code if I hover over it!

However, to my knowledge, there is a function-style checking in Typescript for types that you can pass a type in and expect a type back, and finally assign a value to it to see if it goes through.

### Type-checking using a Generic Type and a follow-up assignment

Using this technique I am thinking about the following template type:

```
type TrueStringLiterals<T extends string> = string extends T ? never : true;

const v1 = "hi";
const check1: TrueStringLiterals<typeof v1> = true; // No error :-)

const v2 = "bye";
const check2: TrueStringLiterals<typeof v2> = true; // No error :-)

const v3 = ("red" as string);
const check3: TrueStringLiterals<typeof v3> = true; // Errors, as expected!
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgVwgZWHAlgOwOYBl3ARwCGANgM4A8MUEAHoZgCblTlpbYB8UAvGxxy0GEZqxoB+KJggA3IlABcUNEgDcAKA0BjAPaZ2UWQEY+UAEQALdOc16DwKNssRtAa2PL4SVBhz5CEgpKUEhdADMjYx5+VQg1KAB6RKgAOV1aODhdOCUAWgBKLXtDWQAmM3MAIxAIWx19Q2dXNzKvRBRBPAIiMipQiAijMpiVDoTktIyibNzFQuLGx1kAZjMACnM4CCZzKGJWdj9sArslpxd3FfafLoDe4IGh1dG4iZSAUSyc8gAafdY9Eg2kITAAhBogA)

#### Easier in an already-passed Generic Type

Also, in my use case, I am doing:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<
    BRAND_T extends (string extends BRAND_T ? never : string),
    VALUE_T = string
> {
...
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=4&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#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)

... which works like a charm!

Comment: `class FirstName extends MyAbstractClass<"FirstName" | "dooo"> {}` is not flagged by the compiler. The reason is the 'distributution of conditional types', I think.

Answer (score 5):

You can create utility type which will allow only on subset of string:

```
type SubString<T> = T extends string ?
    string extends T ? never
    : T
    : never

const makeSubStr = <T extends string>(a: SubString<T>) => a
const a = makeSubStr('strLiteral')
const b = makeSubStr('strLiteral' as string) // error

const c: string = 'elo I am string'
const d = makeSubStr(c) // error

const e: SubString<"red"> = ("red" as string); // error
```

This type will also return `never` if something is not a string, in your answer `TrueStringLiterals` will not take this case into consideration and pass it through.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very close to my own answer.  I believe the `<T extends string>` in my code is catching what you pointed out.  Similarly, I believe you could have made your `SubString` a one-liner like `type SubString<T extends string> = string extends T ? never : T;`.  The difference is on whether you want `x: SubString<number> = 2;` to error on `SubString<number>` type cannot be created in the first place (my way), or to go ahead and errors on assignment to `never` (your way).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to submit an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013395/1730082) from a [similar question I recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73013322/how-do-i-extend-a-type-argument-so-that-it-allows-only-string-literal-types-but), that is far more simple than the examples given so far:

```
type SpecificString<S extends Exclude<string, S>> = S

let test1: SpecificString<"a" | "b" | "c"> // okay
let test2: SpecificString<string> // error

//guaranteed to work where `Exclude<string, T>` wouldn't
let test3: Exclude<SpecificString<"a" | "1">, "1">
test3 = "a" // okay
test3 = "1" // error
```

Basically how this works:

`Exclude<string, "any string literal">` ==> resolves to `string`

`Exclude<string, string>` ==> resolves to `never`

You can call this [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) if you like I guess.

Comment: This appears to be the way to go, thanks for sharing!

Comment: You are providing a utility type (takes <S>).  I was looking for a type.  See the examples in the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't catch the case where the provided type parameter is a union of literal strings. If this shall be explicitly avoided, as could be read from the OPs question, the following solution, based on the other two can be used:

```js
type UnUnion<T, S> = T extends S ? ([S] extends [T] ? T : never) : never;
type NotUnion<T> = UnUnion<T, T>;
type LiteralString<T extends string> = string extends T ? never : NotUnion<T>;
```

where `UnUnion` uses the fact that if `T` is a union, say `'a' | 'b'`, the union is distributed over the rest of the type expression.

```js
(['a'|'b'] extends ['a'] ? ... ) | (['a'|'b'] extends ['b'] ? ...)
```

If `T` is a union, none of these can hold and all the parts turn into `never`.
`NotUnion` reduces this to have just one generic parameter and `LiteralString` just uses its result in case its parameter is not extendable by `string`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgO0QSwPYIDwBUA0MDKAfDALwxYxQAeIUCAJgM4EwD8MAFANr4C6lNOkxhcs-dhQBcMBFABuUAE4BKGNNkLFAblCRYAOVQgU6bMTKITmXOUI7w0cooCuUfCEXIEAcwAyyWkUAQwAbbAFaBmZGDy9vcxgYzx8IoWYKdg0lNRhDYwQ0aztgYABjdBiYOQBGaSwXN1iff0DQjAByIPaYAB8YdoAjdoTO9q0YAHoJquqYAAsg5gdYLMUyipAqgCY6hvdkvwClNqS4kdKxyem5LfnFmGWZeSV1hEq5AGZd1324luOwghnABbAZKEb0S5TB56GBBRTeEF0TbIZioAZyNDORghMAwADuinQ3le7wALN9Ggd-sEwu0qMNSP0GTogA)

Comment: This still fails for template literal types which are infinite unions, but not `string` itself, e.g. `\`a${string}\`` (at least when the intention is to only allow "any one specific string").