# Typescript - Dynamic key names in object? Using template literal?

Tags: typescript

Is something like the following possible?

```
type test = <T extends string>(key: T, object: { [`${T}`]: number }) => void
                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

I know we can set type literal values using that syntax, but I've played around and don't seem to be able to do it with keys.

However, logically, I feel like it should be possible given mapped keys using `as` is possible...

Anybody have any insight into this?

Comment: It would be possible if you could find a way to enforce T to be a literal and not just a generic `string`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185333 but I'm not sure if TS can be made to understand the narrowing out of `string`

Comment: Nope, it's possible! See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Record<T, number>` (I recommend) or classic usage:

```
type test = <T extends string>(key: T, object: { [K in T]: number }) => void
```

Type objects don't work the same as JS objects.

#### EDIT

for more fields, use & (merge) operator:

```
type test = <T extends string>(key: T, object: { [K in T]: number } & {foo: "bar"}) => void
```

or (better)

```
type test = <T extends string>(key: T, object: Record<T, number> & {foo: "bar"}) => void
```

Comment: This works, but not entirely as I had hoped. For example `{[K in T] : number, foo: 'bar'}` doesn't seem to work. Do you have any insight on why?

Comment: Thanks, did you figure this out through experimentation or is there some documentation on what this feature is (i.e. do you have a keyword you can recommend I look up?) I find it extremely counter-intuitive, but perhaps I just am not that familiar with TS yet...

Comment: Of course! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype