# Typescript generic type constraint with conditional type, avoid circular type constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

Suppose the following example class

```js
class X<T> {
  constructor(readonly t: Extract<'a' | 'b', T>) {}
}
```

The point is that the type function `Extract` turns out `never` if the constuctor is called with a wrong parameter, like in

```js
const x = new X('z');
```

**The Problem**: The compiler puts a squiggle below `'z'` telling that it is not assignable to `never`. Hovering over `X(` in vscode only tells us that that the parameter of the constructor should be `never`. There seems to be no indication that the type constraint is actually `Extract(...)`.

**Question**: The error message on the `"z"` as the constructor parameter saying it should be `never` is not very helpful when you not also have the class definition in front of you. Is there a way to rephrase the definition of `class X` such that we better see why the `"z"` is a wrong parameter.

**What I tried**: First I had the type constraint on the generic parameter:

```js
// THIS DOES NOT WORK
class X<T extends Extract<'a' | 'b', T> { ... }
```

Yet, this is not allowed due to a circular type reference.

Note: `Extract` is only used as an example. It could be any more elaborate type function that may return `never` for the actual type parameter. The actual type constraint I would like to use is the [TrueStringLiterals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185333/2954288) constraint.

Comment: It means sense that the second piece of your code doesn't work. You have a circular dependency, you're starting that `T extends Extract`  with `T` inside. Also shouldn't it be `Extract<'a' | 'b', T>`, `Extract` is a type not a implementation of an invocable.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want here? In other words, provide an example of how it should work, and we can go from there.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you use `Extract`. You can just use `union` constraint like [here](https://tsplay.dev/NddLXN)

Comment: @captain-yossarian Extract is only used as an example. It could be any more elaborate type function that may return never for the actual type parameter.

Comment: @Harald please provide an example of using `type function`. Because according to your current example you don't need to use `Extract<'a' | 'b', T>`

Answer (score 1):

You can cook your own error messages

```js
type IsAOrB<T> =
  T extends Extract<'a' | 'b', T> ? T
  : Constraint<`Extract<'a' | 'b', T>`>;

type Constraint<Message> = { [constraint]: Message };
declare const constraint: unique symbol;

class X<T> {
  constructor(readonly t: IsAOrB<T>) {}
}

const x = new X('z');
//              ---
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to
// parameter of type 'Constraint<"Extract<'a' | 'b', T>">'
```

The idea is that no type will match `{ [constraint]: Message }` because `constraint` is a unique symbol, so it's functionally similar to returning `never` but you have your custom message.

I would like to add that it's not super clear what your use case was meant to represent and I don't necessarily advise to do this in the general case, but this pattern is pretty handy for rejecting inputs with a custom error.