# How do I extend a type argument so that it allows only string literal types but not 'string' itself?

Tags: typescript

I need a type that is essentially "any string except for {reservedKeywords}". However, that is apparently [either impossible or tricky and undwieldly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549561/1730082).

I can settle for having to specify the string literals to use.
This is as close as I can get to what I want, using `Exclude<T,K>`:

```
type AnySet<set extends string> = set
let test1: Exclude<AnySet<"a" | "1">, "1">
test1 = "a" //passes correctly
test1 = "1" //fails correctly

let test2: Exclude<AnySet<string>, "1">
test2 = "a" //passes correctly
test2 = "1" //passes (counterintuitively :( )
```

Is there any way I can prohibit passing `string` directly?
Furthermore, is there a way to define a type is any collection of string literals but not specifically a `string`?

Here's what I mean:

```
type AnySet<set extends string> = set
let test1: Exclude<AnySet<"a" | "1">, "1">
test1 = "a" //passes correctly
test1 = "1" //fails correctly

let test2: Exclude<AnySet<string>, "1">
test2 = "a" //passes correctly
test2 = "1" //passes (counterintuitively)

type FiniteSet<set extends ???> = set
let test3: Exclude<FiniteSet<"a" | "1">, "1">
test3 = "a" //should work
test3 = "1" //should not work

let test4: FiniteSet<string> //should fail
let test5: FiniteSet<"a" | "b" | "c"> //should work
```

Comment: It is unconventional to use lowercase names for type parameters.  Please consider changing the unconventional `set` to the more conventional `S`, so that it is not distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a recursive constraint (so-called [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification)) like `S extends Exclude<string, S>`:

```
type FiniteSet<S extends Exclude<string, S>> = S
let test3: Exclude<FiniteSet<"a" | "1">, "1">
test3 = "a" // okay
test3 = "1" // error

let test4: FiniteSet<string> // error
let test5: FiniteSet<"a" | "b" | "c"> // okay
```

This works because [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) filters unions in `T` to remove anything assignable to `U`.  If `T` is `string` then the output will either be `string` (if `string` is a not a subtype of `U`) or `never` (if `string` is a subtype of `U`).  String [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) are subtypes of `string` but not vice-versa, this gives the behavior you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAyhYAeRUIA9gTgEwGcpDgAnASzgHMA+KAXikQFgAoAGxSl1IEYAXFACiWAMYcArvgip4SFKgBEAQyVQAPlCV8ltADTbdtdr2B9G2tVAD0NsCsKEIxMQHsyZCGOAcQpl3NLHXU7ADMVCg5XDy8fP3Z2LmAeQIAmIVEJaVl5ZDRSShoDIz0A0jTg6zsHJxcod09vX382M0qmENt7R2diAAp3SThcIuBJCmAKADcIPwBKRLbwaAAxKkmIfPRMHDwiEXEpGVRCqmpDRFp6JlZObjMAZkyjnNR1uE3t1XUtEJL-uVgI8qqEbIQABZuSQcfBQADuHgA1kCQZ1dN1IdDYVA4G4UoiyCi2EkHoEACxCD5fRRnYqYqEwuERKKklJmACsVI2uG+1j+ACNftoxHoGdi4YSkUA)