# TypeScript type constraint where two strings can be anything as long as they are the same

Tags: typescript

I would like to construct a TypeScript type that ensures that, in an array of objects that each have one key, the keys of those objects are equivalent. The trick is I don't know what that key will be.

For example, In the code below, `good1` and `good2` would pass because `"f1" === "f1"` and `"f2" === "f2"`, and `bad` would fail because `"f3" !== "f4"`.

```
const good1: MyType = [{ f1: 'Hello' }, { f1: 'World' }];
const good2: MyType = [{ f2: 'Hello' }, { f2: 'World' }];

// @ts-expect-error
const bad: MyType = [{ f3: 'Hello' }, { f4: 'World' }];
```

The simple way to do it would be something like `Record<string, string>[]`, but that doesn't constrain the keys at all, nor the number of keys. In the code below, I think I want `f` to be a `const` of some kind instead of just `string`:

```
type MyType = { [f: string]: string }[];

// or if I want a specific number of elements:
type MyTypeTwoElements = [{ [f: string]: string }, { [f: string]: string }];
```

I don't want to use generics in the variable declaration because I don't know what the strings will be, I just know they'll be equivalent (`===`). So this won't work:

```
type MyTypeG<F extends string> = Record<F, string>[];
const withGenericsGood: MyTypeG<"f1"> = [{ f1: 'Hello' }, { f1: 'World' }];
//@ts-expect-error
const withGenericsBad: MyTypeG<"f1"> = [{ f2: 'Hello' }, { f3: 'World' }];
```

There's probably a more general case where any two strings within a type definition must match each other, not necessarily object keys (and more than two, of course).

[TS playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8oG0BmAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6+RZVUAvptQNwBQA9F1APbEopbFACSUAO4BDcsChTCkAMbDSSqOQCuAWwBGEQXxEQANhG0RZBXB1CRYCJPAl8AomYtWoqTBhx0SChoAhkpmABp0LDxCQKpaWNDmdg4OJT5yIihKPj4AEwBGfDhEex8MbCKoAHIACVMTPmqIqMr8aoB1ARM85qYU9My5HPyAJmLHMqwK8Zr6k0a+yJn2ruIevoGMrN0pPInSlGmobABmdvnFloqAFlXu3uTOWyQHQ4BxAB4AMSgIAA9gJY8gREkEAHzeKAAJQg6WIeR+kXoENYnEGWQkpGAAAt3pYDGoCO9cvs3kgvgAiSqUyHlE5VOoNJrXBn3daPfqcHgAAWABAAtADlMAhcRiAI0ts5FjcfjyISlAQAEJ7A4Uz7Ugq0qG+E6zJkLFlMZYnc41NYbJ4cIA).

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool for the problem. What you describe is not a type (compile-time checkable), but a run-time condition. I'd use an `assert` in the functional part of your code rather than type land.

Comment: Playground link is broken.

Comment: There is no specific TypeScript type for this, at least not directly. You can use generics without needing to write out `MyTypeG<"f1">` explicitly; it can be inferred via helper function like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wRXe5m)  But when you say "I don't know what the strings will be" I'm concerned. Is this information available at compile time at all? Or is it only known at runtime? If the former there are approaches; if the latter then it's impossible. Anyway, if my link above works for you I can write up an answer explaining. Let me know (mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I'm using a type guard function (`const isMyType = (obj: any): obj is MyType => { /* logic here */ }`) that ensures the condition at runtime, I was just wondering if there was a way to help the IDE know during development that the two strings cannot be different. Feel free to write up an answer based on the helper function.

Comment: I've seen a "not-union" type floating around before. Maybe something like this could work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70731144/6253337

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript which corresponds to what you hope `MyType` to be.  It would essentially need to be an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Record<F, string>[]` for every string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `F`, like

```
type MyType = Record<"", string>[] | Record<"a", string>[] | Record<"b", string>[] | ... | 
  Record<"foobar", string>[] | ... | 
  Record<"It was the best of times, it was the blurst of times", string>[] | ...
```

but TypeScript doesn't support infinite unions.  Conceptually an infinite union is equivalent to an [*existentially quantified generic type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), where you say that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter *exists* but you don't know or care about what it is:

```
type MyType = <exists F extends_oneof string> Record<F, string>[];
```

but TypeScript supports neither `exists` to represent existential types (although requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) nor `extends_oneof` to represent that `F` should range over single literals and not unions of literals (although requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) more or less) so you can't really us that approach directly either.

---

Generally speaking I'd say that the closest you can reasonably get is to use regular generics, as you showed:

```
type MyTypeG<F extends string> = Record<F, string>[];
```

and use a generic helper identity function to infer the generic type argument `F` without having to manually specify it:

```
const myTypeG = <F extends string>(x: MyTypeG<F>) => x;
```

As you can test here:

```
const withGenericsGood = myTypeG([{ f1: 'Hello' }, { f1: 'World' }]); // okay
const withGenericsBad = myTypeG([{ f2: 'Hello' }, { f3: 'World' }]); // error
```

The `withGenericsGood` line works because `myTypeG()` infers `"f1"` as `F` and so you get a `MyTypeG<"f1">` without having to write it out explicitly.  The `withGenericsBad` line fails because `myTypeG()` infers `F` to be the union `"f2" | "f3"`, and neither of the inputs contain both keys.  That's not exactly the reason you want this to fail, but it's fairly close.  Still, if you *really* care, you could try to encode all your constraints like this:

```
type NotAUnion<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? U extends any ?
    T extends U ? unknown : never : never : never

type StringLiteral<T> = string extends T ? never :
    [T] extends [string & NotAUnion<T>] ? unknown : never;

type MyTypeGInfer<F extends string> = [
    Record<F, string> & StringLiteral<F>,
    ...Record<F & {}, string>[]
];

const myTypeG = <F extends string>(x: MyTypeGInfer<F>): MyTypeG<F> => x;
```

where we use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to collapse any unions to `never` in `NotAUnion<T>`, and other conditional types to ensure that `T` is a string literal type and not a union of literals or `string`, and then we use `MyTypeGInfer<F>` to play inference tricks so that `F` will be inferred just from the first element of the passed in array and that it will check if `F` is a single string literal and become `never` otherwise.  Thus you get the following behavior:

```
myTypeG([{ f1: 'Hello' }, { f1: 'World' }]); // okay
myTypeG([{ f2: 'Hello' }, { f3: 'World' }]); // error, excess property
myTypeG([]); // error, not enough arguments
myTypeG([{ f1: "abc" }]); // okay
myTypeG([{ f1: "abc", f2: "bcd" }, { f1: "cde", f2: "def" }]) // error, not assignable to never
myTypeG([{ ["ab" + "c"]: "abc" }]) // error, not assignable to never
```

The last one fails because `"ab" + "c"` is known only as a `string` to the compiler, and thus it can't tell what the key actually is, so it complains.

Personally I think that's probably overkill unless you actually expect people to be doing crazy things with `myTypeG()`.

---

There are also ways to encode existential types in TypeScript, and but they involve `Promise`-like inversions of control:

```
type SomeMyType = <R, >(cb: <F extends string>(x: MyTypeG<F>) => R) => R;
const someMyType = <F extends string>(x: MyTypeG<F>): SomeMyType => cb => cb(x);

const someGood = someMyType([{ f1: 'Hello' }, { f1: 'World' }]); // okay
const someBad = someMyType([{ f2: 'Hello' }, { f3: 'World' }]); // error
```

The `SomeMyType` type isn't generic, but it's holding onto a `MyTypeG<F>` for some `F` you don't know and it can't tell you. All you can do is give it a generic callback that returns you some type `R` for any `MyTypeG<F>` in existence, and then it gives you back an `R`.  The `MyTypeG<F>` is held in a black box where `F` is unobservable to you.  This completely encodes the existential type, but it's not trivial to use:

```
function someMyTypeToStringArray(smt: SomeMyType) {
    return smt(x => {
        const k = Object.keys(x[0])[0] as keyof typeof x[number]; 
        // hopefully this is of type F, whatever F is

        return x.map(v => v[k])
    })
}

console.log(someMyTypeToStringArray(someGood).join(" ")); // Hello World
```

So I wouldn't recommend this unless your need for existentials outweighs the need for ease of use.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/PTAEAkFMBsAdIE6gOKQHaIJYGMBQuAXAT3lAFkiAVEyZAHgDFRIAPA9AEwGdQuCFMaAOYA+UAF5QAJUjYA9gg6MANL36DRAbQC6AbnzFSAOTkEAggFU0mOWjqUxkzZW3M2nHpsEAzRKAuuAPz+buxo3KAAhmhEoIG4oImglKEeIcEArmgA1mhyAO5ooABcoBgAbn6lFVVlkJUIBjSgAMrqwgAymOwIkdD2jmoCwqnhPCnBNUjFCUnOrqxhEZp8w0KgAGSgJuZWNnYOQaBZuQVF1fWI+oTNFNTwyACSaL4IjKMRqxqDmrOJMvJFCoht9Nq12kIuj0+owRMo-qAAHTIgEKJRMLYAbwAvqovsIRDpcHp8PI0HxQABbKg0ZASUDvRZpfGiAAULFKd1pz1esIAlJyaQ9YRIxCx9GSKflugALVAYATYLjIORyDj06n3WiszSY0DeACMpQA5FBoNA5MbQLjQHrDSaAOoKaAcK3Y7R8iW2KWy+VYJUAIUi6skmtpOrtACYTWaLW7VHaAMyO52u60e3SgEDMBAIBSqVjYSBcHiwPPwBDEXBhh46jNZsCIPMIVR5AjMPIZIQyqIIIQZSnoAhcatC7W6-VG0AAIkiACNsNP056G6A5NlIkRR1rkBHJ6VZwvp6pvNGZwuOEubXap9PsBxIMf9Wfpw-vFePaum-myqYoiXMCENB52gSBQAIOQ6gabdwwnTRDyXABqGdF20A950XZcv1zH823-LhAOAudQPAyCpnwXBswAURYTA+CHTA+hHG5SBaORBy5UhJDoKRVBEVlsDnUpGXcMYQQJdlBR3flRWkPlZKkL1yXbLh2MgTiwO4pgmTEll+I5cgx3oBgRAFVo1I02TBKsud2U9CjJRUtSVTVelVI4sc93tUBTRgONrQTfcfKdBAXTdets3XTdcEc3g1KDEM4o8rUvLPXzzUtALbX1ZNgtTcKV2zb9GlwbwsmwAh9iS9Sx0oOQ2jWMxc03VkuEpAhSjY5KaHkzEEQQSACAyBAijagh2Vkvqkmm0BYuyekAHk5wAK1kAhEWySAiC4dlNAABg9fbXEiHhNqIORvHAmgLtAFhNDQAc50QPRVxlOR4DK81YgIGU6NAP6bsMMCGFUfIZUidgGlAJg6IRaaBqGkbbsRSlIlgVlylk8pNGyD0EWxPlcGxUlvTkUDEQtIRWos2r6ohJreiIanBxcjg+URZa5EEVkl2nPlCrAWNIJCl0gA)